# while(line.contains("^")) loop not breaking

Tags: writer, reader

this is my class:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
  {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file2.txt"));
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("file.txt"));

    int i = 0;
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      while(line.contains("^")) {
        i ++;
        line = line.replaceFirst("^", Integer.toString(i));
      }
      bw.write(line + "\n");
    }
    br.close();
    bw.close();
  }
}
```

the file2.txt and file.txt are exactly the same and I want to make the lines that look like

```
<wpt lat="26.381418638" lon="-80.101236298"><ele>0</ele><time> </time><name>Waypoint #^</name><desc> </desc></wpt>
```

to look like

```
<wpt lat="26.381418638" lon="-80.101236298"><ele>0</ele><time> </time><name>Waypoint #5</name><desc> </desc></wpt>
```

When I run it though, it goes on an infinite loop. Any advice will help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
line = line.replaceFirst("^", Integer.toString(i));
```

`replaceFirst`'s first argument is a regular expression, and `"^"` as a regular expression means "the start of the string". So this command just keeps prepending values to the start of the string, and never removes any circumflexes. Instead, you should write:

```
line = line.replaceFirst("\\^", Integer.toString(i));
```

Answer (score 1):

The String.replaceFirst method takes a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) which has special characters for certain operations - one of these characters is the`^` character. You need to escape it to look for occurances of it (In Java, since backslash is special in strings, this would be `"\\^"` in the "replaceFirst" argument)